# How to discover if lazy loading is working or not

Tags: reactjs, webpack, lazy-loading, bundle

I am in middle of optimising my react app bundle. Current size is 1.4MB. Implemented Lazy loading in routers. While running the app at localhost, i can see lazy loading working well in Network tab of browser, I see first initial chunk loads and render's in the browser then rest of the 1.4MB comes. Problem comes when i create a production bundle and deploy it to server, there entire 1.4MB loads and then can see rendering.

Is there something missing during production bundle creation? How to check if lazy loading is working from server?

Webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const { resolve } = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
var CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin');

process.env.BABEL_ENV = 'production';
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
    entry: './src/index.jsx',
    resolve: {
        fallback: { crypto: false },
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json', '.wasm'],
        enforceExtension: false,
        alias: {
            process: resolve('node_modules/process')
        }
    },
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$|jsx/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules[/\\\\](?!(mesh-component-library|mesh-icon-library)[/\\\\]).*/
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'style-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.sass$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'style-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jp(e*)g|svg|gif)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: 'images/[hash]-[name].[ext]'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ process: 'process/browser' }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: './public/index.html' }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: 'styles.css' }),
        new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin({
            NODE_ENV: process.env.BABEL_ENV,
            BABEL_ENV: process.env.NODE_ENV
        }),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
        }),
        new CompressionPlugin({
            algorithm: "gzip",
            threshold: 10240,
            minRatio: 0.8
          })
    ]
};
```

Package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest --watchAll=false --coverage",
    "testWithResults": "jest --json --outputFile=./testResults.json",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --config webpack.config.js --open --port 4000",
    "build": "webpack --mode production --config webpack.config.js",
    "eslint": "eslint src/**/*.js*"
},
```

Comment: What are you using to build/bundle the app? Are you using `create-react-app` and the default `react-scripts`, it should manage this automatically? or have you a custom webpack? Can you share the webpack configuration if managing this yourself? Check with the [webpack code splitting](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/) guide linked from the React docs.

Comment: It's custom webpack.

Comment: @DrewReese I have updated the post with webpack details. please have a look. Thanks

Comment: `Implemented Lazy loading in routers. While running the app at localhost, i can see lazy loading working well in Network tab of browser, I see first initial chunk loads and render's in the browser then rest of the 1.4MB comes.` That all needs clarification. Should try to provide a reproducible example. For example, how exactly are you doing lazy loading?

Answer (score 3):

Try configuring webpack SplitChunksPlugin to include all.

Add this section to your webpack config.

```
optimization: {
  splitChunks: {
    chunks: 'all',
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the [Webpack bundle analyzer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer), it has helped me differentiate between bundle sizes before and after implementing dynamic loading recently. The implementation is quite simple, they've mentioned it in the docs. It's easy to understand the differences in size as well as everything is visual. Hope this helps!